# Strange escape sequences in terminal

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, file-manager, kitty, nnn

I have kitty, and I use nnn as file manager.
I actiavted the "preview-tui" plugin in nnn.
When I hover over a folder, I see something like this:
[image]

What are those strange escape sequences?

Answer (score 2):

The `<ESC>[...m` escapes are color codes. It looks like you're looking at the output with `less` (or the tools are running `less` for you).

`less` can be made to display the colors with the `-R` option. I.e. `less -R`, or set the `LESS` environment variable to include `R` (among any other options you need). You can get similar issues with `git`, if you have the `LESS` envvar set, but without including `-R`.